# How to exclude folder from Web Setup project in VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, web-setup-project

I want to exclude a folder in a web application from a web setup project in VS2010. I've gone in to the Content Files -> Exclude Filter option in order to filter out some specific files and this works fine. However, I want to exclude a directory called "External" from the root of the web project,and no matter what I put in the Exclude Filter it always includes it.

Does anybody know if this option is supposed to be able to exclude folders as opposed to individual files? There are too many to include individually. I've tried rules like the following:

1. External\*
2. \External\*
3. ~\External\*

all to no avail.

Also, I have seen some people mention putting special blocks in the setup project file to exclude stuff, but I couldn't figure out where to put this, or what file they were talking about. If this is the way to do it, some guidance as to where to put the rules would be appreciated.

I don't want to exclude the folder from the solution project itself, I just want two setup projects, one that includes the folder, one that does not.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After some research I can't find anything that suggests that you can exclude folders.

You can however edit the csproj-file and set some  `<ExcludeFromBuild>`-tags
http://www.meadow.se/wordpress/exclude-files-and-folders-from-web-deployment-projects/
This will have the desired effect.